# Ubuntu Installer moved my C drive somewhere else :( please help

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu incorrectly while experimenting with it and have inadvertently screwed my original system.

I have a 120GbSSD to boot Windows 7 from and a 1TB D: drive.
the SSD was a clean installation of Windows 7, the D drive was partitioned at 300Gb for Windows Games and then planned on using smaller partitions for several Ubuntu installs.

I used the Ubuntu installer to create the main folder on the D: drive and the swap area, but I left the drive to install boot/MBR on as C drive. I now realise this is wrong but need some help trying to recover my Windows 7 installation as I have valuable need for it.

What has happened is that Ubuntu seams to have taken control of the C drive and installed its own partition as the root/boot - grub only see's ubuntu on it, but the original C drive contents now shows up in e:
the windows setup disk wont see the original C: Windows 7 installation or the e: drive copy of the original c drive.

I really want to get my E: drive back to C: and fix the Windows MBR and then install Ubuntu properly so it boots from grub but is installed on a partition on the d: drive.

I really appreciate any help you could give, even if its really low level stuff.
Thanks :)

Comment: PS. I have tried all forms of windows repair and use of bootrec.  It seems something odd has happened with the partitioning on the C drive. I just want to get it back to how it was, but the Windows 7 install disk cant do it however I try.  thanks

Comment: Sounds like you installed over your Windows boot manager and C drive, a screenshot of your partitions would really help, boot a live DVD/USB and run gparted. " I have tried all forms of windows repair" This will of made things worse, Windows thinks it is the only OS in the world and will just break anything it does not understand.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feed back mark - Ubuntu is still working as the only bootable OS now, if I boot using the Wind 7 disk it see's C drive as empty - but the original C drive is now on E:  - I will run Gparted from there and try get a screen shotinstall I will get a screen shot to you. How do I send images on here?

Comment: Just upload to imgur.com and link it here, this may help you http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing-components/storage/how-to-move-your-operating-system-to-another-hard-drive-1296831 I know it says move HDD, but swap that for partitions in clonezilla.

Comment: Hi - here are the screen shots from Gparted, the first one is the current state of sda, the second is sdb. Originally sda (the 120Gb SSD) had two partitions - a SYSTEM partition (100mb) and approx 111Gb Which was windows 7. sdb (the 1Tb) had a 300Gb partition for games / windows use.  During install I added two small 20Gb partitions to D for Ubuntu. sda now imgur.com/zxPvwti - sdb now imgur.com/V5FMjWq . the original C Drive is intact on what is now E drive, but I did not have an e drive when I started.  could this be that odd partition in the middle of no where on sdb? can I reconstruct C:?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

What had happened was the Ubuntu installer had taken over my SYSTEM 100Mb hidden folder and installed itself there. The installer did create the two 20Gb partitions, but appeared to have created another partition further into the 2nd drive for its system files called UBUNTU (see pics above). The Original C: drive containing my Windows 7 was still intact, however when booting into the Windows 7 set up CD and getting to command prompt it was identified as G:

So I assumed that what had happened was that Ubuntu had deleted my SYSTEM partition and used it for itself, and the Windows setup boot was enumerating the original C: drive as an additional drive G: (E: in the UI ), and Windows 7 original SYSTEM partition was now C: drive containing Ubuntu system files but all hidden.

A little research on how SYSTEM is built and repaired yielded these two links.

http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/231133-recover-windows-7-100mb-system-reserved-partition.html

The solution was to boot off Win 7 setup disk (you may have to play around with UEFI type settings in the BIOS to get Windows setup to see your original Windows C: drive - it came up as E: for during system setup boot, I don't know why, but sometimes the Windows setup disk saw nothing at all, so persevere with some of the UEFI and other boot type parameters in the BIOS if this happens)

So startup off your Windows setup disk again, get to command prompt...type these three commands in this order

> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /fixboot
>
> bootrec /rebuildbcd

and then restart.  This rebuilt my SYSTEM partition for windows and then I could boot and remove the spurious partitions created for Ubuntu. Hey presto back to square one, and I won't ever make my original mistake again! ;)

Thanks for your help mark you gave me confidence to progress this.
Ciao!